# Code Blocks: clang default compiler settings

Tags: clang, codeblocks

I'm using clang 3.6 (nightly built) in windows with Code Blocks. Everything works great but the following warning is bothering me:

```
warning: 'auto' type specifier is incompatible with C++98 [-Wc++98-compat]
```

I can see that the command line is:

```
clang++.exe -Weverything -fexceptions  -g -std=c++14    -I...
```

Where do the first two settings come from? I have checked the global and project compiler setting but nowhere do I set -Weverything.

Answer (score 0):

You can try editing your `.cbp` file (the code::blocks project file) with an editor and try finding the `-Weverything` switch there.

Look for something like this...

```
    <Compiler>
        <Add option="-Wall" />
        <Add option="-fexceptions" />
    </Compiler>
```

I'm using gcc but you should find something similar for clang